# Node.js - Função retornando o valor da consulta?

Tags: node.js, express.js

É o seguinte tentei procurar mas não encontrei nenhuma solução, to tentanto criar uma função no model da minha aplicação que vai retornar os dados da consulta no banco. Essa função seria chamada no meu controller que posteriormente seria enviado para o arquivo da página.

Função que faz a consulta

```
exports.show = function(){
    var result;
    connection.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query('select 1 + 1 as teste', function(err, rows){
            this.result = rows[0].teste;
            connection.release();
            console.log('---->', this.result);
            return this.result;
        });
    });
};
```

Controller

```
var Model = require('../models/Models');

exports.Index = function(request, response){
    response.pageInfo = {};

    response.pageInfo.title = 'Users';
    response.pageInfo.users = Model.show(); 
    response.render('user/index', response.pageInfo);
};
```

E a página .jade

```
extends ../layout
block content
    h1 #{users}
```

E ao executar desse jeito simplismente não imprime o valor na página, mas no console funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou responder sem ter toda a certeza, pois não sei por exemplo que BD estás a usar.

O primeiro problema que vejo é quando chamas:

```
response.pageInfo.users = Model.show();
```

Isso vai começar código que é assíncrono. Ou seja, esse código vai fazer uma chamada à base de dados mas o resto do código não vai esperar! Ou seja: `response.render('user/index', response.pageInfo);` vai ser corrido antes da resposta da BD voltar.

Depois tem outro problema aí: quando fazes `return this.result;` isso não vai retornar nada para `response.pageInfo.users =`. Primeiro porque está dentro de 2 funções e o return não faz ambas darem `return`, somente aquela onde o `return` está; e em segundo porque isto é assíncrono e `response.pageInfo.users =` já tem valor e o código já correu.

#### O que fazer?

Usa uma callback que permita usar a informação/dados quando eles estiverem prontos.

Acho que no Jade tens de usar os dados no segundo parametro de `response.render` e não como propriedade de `response`.

Sugestão de código:

```
exports.show = function(callback){
    var result;
    connection.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query('select 1 + 1 as teste', function(err, rows){
            this.result = rows[0].teste;
            connection.release();
            console.log('---->', this.result);
            return callback(this.result);
        });
    });
};
```

Controller

```
var Model = require('../models/Models');

exports.Index = function(request, response){
    Model.show(function(users){
        response.render('user/index', {
            users: users,
            title: 'Users'
        });
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Verdade, cara. Eu tinha feito de um modo que ao carregar a a página pela segunda vez aparecia o resultado do banco de dados(MySQL), mas fiz seguindo as suas instruções e deu certo aqui. Muito obrigado!!!!!! (Comecei a estudar Node.js a dois dias e já estou bastante empolgado)

Comment: @Liw.S. ótimo! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite :)