# Como pegar o valor de uma função dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, node.js

Pessoal não estou conseguindo pegar o valor da "var stop" para usar em outros lugares apenas aparece no console. Alguém pode me ajudar a retornas por favor?!

Obrigado!!

```
game = require('./../model/Game.model')()// Aqui busco meu model de Schema mongooseJS.
modules = require('./../model/modules'); // Aqui estou chamando a minha pagina de funções (modulos).
var result = modules.getResult(game); //Aqui estou buscando o resultado na ma minha função a qual tenho dúvida.
```

-----------------------Pagina de models---------------------------------------------

```
var Models = function(){

    this.getResult = function(game){
        //game.findOne uso para pesquisar no meu banco de dados o game que está em progresso. Essa ferramenta é do mongooseJS pois meu bd é todo em JSON Ex. gamesDB{gameId:116, gameStatus:"in progress", gameResult: 100.99;}
        game.findOne({gameStatus:'in progress'}, function(err, gamesDB){
            if(err){throw err}
            var stop = gamesDB.gameResult; //Aqui ele traz para mim o resultado de meu banco de dados 100.98
            //console.log(stop); // Aqui ele retorna no console perfeitamente
            return stop; // Quero usar esse valor e não consigo, fica como indefinido =(
        });
     }
   //se a var stop estivesse aqui funcionaria de boa
}
module.exports = new Models();
```

Comment: `game.findOne` é provavelmente assíncrona. Onde queres usar essa variável `stop`? noutra função?

Comment: isso mesmo Sergio, porém essa função fica em outra parte do dessa minha pagina de módulos. Vou apenas chamar ela para apresentar esse resultado Ex: test = modules.sumTotalBets(game); Aqui chamaria o resultado do return da função

Comment: Tens de chamá-la dentro dessa função. Como neste caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/79960/129

Comment: Aparece esse erro:  TypeError: callback is not a function.  Fiz alguns testes de callback aqui porém apenas nessa função não funciona, eu devo estar fazendo algo errado

Comment: Não digo que tenhas de copiar o código de lá, mas o problema é o mesmo. Onde tens agora `return stop;` deves ter `aTuaFuncao(stop);`, e assim chamares essa função que precisa do valor de `stop`.  faz sentido?

Comment: Fiz assim como esta nessa foto porém não sei onde chamo [link](http://clicabarato.com.br/teste.html)

Comment: Podes fazer um diagrama do fluxo desse código? is, quando chamas `game.findOne` o que acontece/o que faz essa função e qual a função que chamas a seguir? Na imagem em cima tens uma função `teste` que não tens aqui na pergunta... ou então mostra mais código para perceber o fluxo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58757/discussion-between-rodrigo-araujo-and-sergio).